# Identify a mounted volume as a CD/DVD on osx

Tags: c++, c, macos, bash, filesystems

When you mount anything on osx it shows up under /Volumes/mountname

Is there any way, using the commandline or C/C++ to identify the volume as a CD/DVD rom?

My current best idea goes something like this.

```
df | grep mountname
```

to get the /dev/diskNsM path

and then

```
drutil | grep /dev/diskN
```

to see if the path mounted device is the burner.

This works, but i'm concerned about the case where the CD/DVD is not a burner. Will it still show up in the output of drutil? Do macs even come with a non-burner CD/DVD drive?

Also i would prefer using C,C++ or objective C to do this.

I already use

```
const char *tmp = '/Volumes/mysterydrive';
statfs(tmp, &m);
if(m.f_flags & MNT_RDONLY)
{
    read_only = true;
}
```

to determine if the volume is readonly,
but i cannot see if this or any related call can distinguish between a CD/DVD and a readonly mounted volume.

It would only need to work for OSX 10.5 and newer.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Using

```
  diskutil info /Volumes/mysterydrive
```

I got the following output if its a CD/DVD

```
  Optical Drive Type:       CD-ROM, CD-R, CD-RW, DVD-ROM, DVD-R, DVD-R DL, DVD-RW, DVD+R, DVD+R DL, DVD+RW
  Optical Media Type:       DVD-R
  Optical Media Erasable:   No
```

And that's all i need!

I'll look into using IOKit to do it programmatically later, but this seems to be the quickest way to get it done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the most detailed information from

```
diskutil info /Volume/foo
```

In particular see *Optical Drive* and *Optical Media* entries which you only get for CD/DVDs so it is quite reliable.

Unfortunately the frameworks that *diskutil* uses to get all that information are private, so it will be hard to replicate it in C code.

I didn't dig deeper into other options, but since you can get the disk name from `statfs` it may be in theory possible to use `IOKit` to check out the device and you'll see `IOCDMedia`  or `IODVDMedia` class if it is a CD/DVD drive (i.e. if you look for `IO*Media` class the `BSD Name` property has the disk name like `disk6`)

Answer (score 2):

Apple Developer Central has a sample code project called [*CDROMSample*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CDROMSample/Listings/CDROMSample_CDROMSample_c.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000423-CDROMSample_CDROMSample_c-DontLinkElementID_3) that shows using `IOKit` routines to access CD-ROM properties. This might give you a start into handling DVDs, as well.